# Repainting measurement increments on tools

Tags: hardware, paint

I have an old pair of calipers I've been trying to look new.
The measurement scales have all their grooves but it's difficult to see them.
Other than taking a pin and painting each line individually is there another way?

Possibly a thin layer of paint and sand off revealing whatever is left in grooves.

Answer (score 6):

You are right on track with painting the surface, but you should act *before the paint dries*.

Either cover the entire scale with paint or add a dollop or line of paint at one end, use a bench scraper to spread the paint over the scale, ideally back and forth. Scrape or wipe the excess paint off again with a rag, so that only the grooves remain coloured. Aim to work mainly perpendicular to the direction of the grooves so as not to remove the paint in them.

This technique is well-known in all [intaglio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intaglio_(printmaking)) types of printing, e.g. etching.

Answer (score 5):

[Sugru](https://sugru.com) - not cheap, but simple & resilient.
(No affiliation, I just use it a lot for all sorts of things)

From Sugru's own web site - [8 ways sugru can refresh and improve well worn products](https://sugru.com/blog/7-ways-sugru-can-refresh-and-improve-well-worn-products)

Rub a contrasting colour into the 'grain' of the markings & rub off the excess. Leave overnight to cure. Starts off like 'plasticine/silly putty' modelling clay - dries like rubberised plastic.
Amongst other uses, I've had some on chipped cups that I use every day & that go in the dishwasher all the time. Still sound after several years.

One example...

[image]

I just realised in the example they appear to be using some kind of wooden palette knife or spatula. I've found a thumb is quite sufficient; it's nowhere near as messy as the pic makes it out to be, thumb, finger, one piece of kitchen roll, done.

Comment: It may well be - let's qualify my statement by saying 'it's not messy enough that you really need an 'implement' to apply it' ;-)

Answer (score 2):

(first answer on stack exchange ever, so please be gentle with me)

Rub a wax crayon along the grooves, the wax will collect in them, any excess wax on the surface can then be easily wiped off.  I can't say it's the most durable or permanent solution, but it's quick and wax crayons are both very cheap and come in a wide variety of bright colours.

In the tabletop gaming world, this is how we restore the pips on our various die when they lose their pigment/ink/paint etc.

Comment: They made a special product for this in the days that all knobs had paint filled dial markings.  The modern replacement is a oil stick as the purpose made products are not common.  -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_stick